# Where is Rust storing all these bytes?

Tags: rust

In trying to understand how stack memory works, I wrote the following code to display addresses of where data gets stored:

```
fn main() {
    let a = "0123456789abcdef0";
    let b = "123456789abcdef01";
    let c = "23456789abcdef012";

    println!("{:p} {}", &a, a.len());
    println!("{:p} {}", &b, b.len());
    println!("{:p} {}", &c, c.len());
}
```

The output is:

```
0x7fff288a5448 17
0x7fff288a5438 17
0x7fff288a5428 17
```

It implies that all 17 bytes are stored in a space of 16 bytes, which can't be right. My one guess is that there's some optimization happening, but I get the same results even when I build with `--opt-level 0`.

The equivalent C seems to do the right thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char a[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    char b[] = "123456789abcdef0";
    char c[] = "23456789abcdef01";

    printf("%p %zu\n", &a, strlen(a) + 1);
    printf("%p %zu\n", &b, strlen(b) + 1);
    printf("%p %zu\n", &c, strlen(c) + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7fff5837b440 17
0x7fff5837b420 17
0x7fff5837b400 17
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String literals `"..."` are stored in static memory, and the variables `a`, `b`, `c` are just (fat) pointers to them. They have type `&str`, which has the following layout:

```
struct StrSlice {
    data: *const u8,
    length: uint
}
```

where the `data` field points at the sequence of bytes that form the text, and the `length` field says how many bytes there are.

On a 64-bit platform this is 16-bytes (and on a 32-bit platform, 8 bytes). The real equivalent in C (ignoring null termination vs. stored length) would be storing into a `const char*` instead of a `char[]`, changing the C to this prints:

```
0x7fff21254508 17
0x7fff21254500 17
0x7fff212544f8 17
```

i.e. the pointers are 8 bytes apart.

You can check these low-level details using `--emit=asm` or `--emit=llvm-ir`, or clicking the [corresponding button on the playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/) (possibly adjusting the optimisation level too). E.g.

```
fn main() {
    let a = "0123456789abcdef0";
}
```

compiled with `--emit=llvm-ir` and no optimisations gives (with my trimming and annotations):

```
%str_slice = type { i8*, i64 }

;; global constant with the string's text
@str1042 = internal constant [17 x i8] c"0123456789abcdef0"

; Function Attrs: uwtable
define internal void @_ZN4main20h55efe3c71b4bb8f4eaaE() unnamed_addr #0 {
entry-block:
  ;; create stack space for the `a` variable
  %a = alloca %str_slice

  ;; get a pointer to the first element of the `a` struct (`data`)...
  %0 = getelementptr inbounds %str_slice* %a, i32 0, i32 0
  ;; ... and store the pointer to the string data in it
  store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([17 x i8]* @str1042, i32 0, i32 0), i8** %0

  ;; get a pointer to the second element of the `a` struct (`length`)...
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %str_slice* %a, i32 0, i32 1
  ;; ... and store the length of the string (17) in it.
  store i64 17, i64* %1
  ret void
}
```

Comment: The C equivalent gives me `0x400664 16`, `0x400674 16` and `0x400684 16`. I suppose this is because the `const char*`s are not stored in the stack, as you seem to imply?

Comment: @Tshepang, that is the equivalent to the Rust: with a `const char* a = "01234..."` the string data is stored in static memory. Although, that data looks like you're printing `a`, rather than `&a`. The only change you need to make to your C is `char ...[]` to `const char* ...`. Don't change the `printf` lines.

Comment: Given that StrSlice is gone, what is the today equivalent of that struct?

Comment: It hasn't changed. The type defined here was never something in the standard library.